# how to get a input-value to a form-action?

Tags: html, forms

I'm trying to "connect" an input-field with a search-query. This is my code:

```
<form method="get" action="{{ base_url_relative }}/search/query:HERETHEVALUE">                  
    <input id="searchfield" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Suche." >
</form>
```

The value of the searchfield should be added to this place, where HERETHEVALUE is.
With the name="search" there's always a ?search=VALUE added.

How I can add the value to the placeholder or remove the ?search= ?
Is this possible?

Comment: To remove `?search=`, change the form's method to `POST`.

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/xehcujwq/1/

Comment: @stealthyninja: sadly, this doesn't add the value of the input-field behind the {{ base_url_relative }}/search/query:

Answer (score 1):

If your form attribute is set to GET, the browser appends the querystring to the action method.

So in your example, the request to the server on submit will look like: ../search/query?searchfield=value

Answer (score 1):

One way I can think of achieving what you want would be to employ some jQuery to intercept the form, e.g.

**HTML:**

```
<form id="searchform" method="post" action="{{ base_url_relative }}/search/query:HERETHEVALUE">
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$( "#searchform" ).submit( function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // I suggest making an Ajax request here to a processing script to check 
    // the validity of the data that was entered to the search. Presuming all 
    // went well and the data is available in your database, redirect the user:
    document.location = "{{ base_url_relative }}/search/query:" + $( "#searchfield" ).val();
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the query, it happens automatically. You will have to receive it at the next page.

```
<?php
$search_query = $_GET['search'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the method of the form action is GET, no need to add the value, ut will be added directly by the browser action.
If the method is set to 'POST', the search value will be disappeared from the query link. You can get the value using PHP by:

```
$value = $_POST['search'];
```

or

```
extract($_POST);

use directly $search
```